# Prestashop 1.5 Tools::getPageName error when _PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_ enabled

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I am trying to tweak Prestashop productivity, but when I enable

```
define('_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_', true);
```

i get php fatal error on all front-end pages:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Tools::getPageName() in /override/classes/Link.php on line 32
```

In admin panel debug output works perfectly. I tryed to search for such an error on the community forums but failed. My Prestashop version is 1.5.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Tools` class doesn't have a `getPageName` method. You should remove the method call from the overridden `Link` class.

Comment: i know what it literally means. But 1) removing just like this is not an option since it's a body of getPaginationLink function in Link.php  - it's probably handy for pagination; 2) everything works consistently, until _PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_ isn't enabled, probably even by commenting out Tools::getPageName() there will be other fatal error.

Comment: @shershen I checked it and in PrestaShop 1.5 the `Tools` class has no `getPageName` method. Does the `/override/classes/Tools` file contain this method?

Comment: nope. should I then add it myself from other version?

Comment: @shershen You should implement the method or remove the method call. There is no `getPageName` method in PrestaShop 1.4 either. It is difficult to tell what to do without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but maybe someone will need an answer. 
In PrestaShop 1.5 profiling includes it's own override for Tools class (in tools/profiling). So if you have your own overriden Tools class with method getPageName() you need to change it's name or move this method to Core class.